# How can I store a list of directories in an array?

Tags: arrays, bash, directory

Why this does not list anything? Thank you

```
FOLDER=()

ls /tmp/backup/ | while read DIR
do
    FOLDER+=("$DIR")
done

echo ${FOLDER[1]}
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Analysis

Your example is designed to fail. For example:

- Don't parse the output of `ls`.
- Don't assume every entry in a directory is a directory.
- Don't append arrays in a loop without a good reason.
- Don't use unquoted variables.

#### Use Shell Globs

Assuming that every entry in /tmp/backup is a directory, you can simply use shell globs to populate your array. If you may have files as well as directory entries, then you'll need to use *find* or use a shell test expression to ensure that the entry is actually a directory. For example:

```
# Enable special handling to prevent expansion to a
# literal '/tmp/backup/*' when no matches are found. 
shopt -s nullglob

FOLDERS=(/tmp/backup/*)
for folder in "${FOLDERS[@]}"; do
    [[ -d "$folder" ]] && echo "$folder"
done

# Unset shell option after use, if desired. Nullglob
# is unset by default.
shopt -u nullglob
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to turn on the `nullglob` option, so that the glob isn't treated literally if the directory is empty.

Comment: Don't call directory folder! ;-)

Comment: That was another bullet for the analysis list.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker That's just to preserve the semantics for the OP. You can call the variable anything you want, but your point is well taken.

Comment: @CodeGnome, that's why I added my second comment — it wasn't meant as a correction to your answer, but rather an addition to your list of flaws ;)

Comment: @CodeGnome why not to append arrays in a loop?

Comment: @nshy Because it's slower, requires longer and longer string assignment operations, can cause off-by-one errors, and may introduce quoting issues. YMMV.

Comment: @CodeGnome I thought arrays in bash are associative(some hashes probably) so there shouldn't be great performance penalties.

Comment: @nshy Associative arrays are declared and populated differently. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html. Feel free to open a new question if you want to explore the issue, but this comment thread has grown long enough.

Comment: If you don't need an array for some other reason, just iterate over the glob directly.

Answer (score 3):

To work around subshellissue (see Diego's answer), you can also do something like

```
while ....
done <<<$(ls)
```

Comment: This is the right way to deal with both scope and possible spaces in file names.

Comment: @Raphink, space handling depends on what's in the `while`. I'd recommend `IFS= read f` or some such

Comment: By default, `while` uses newlines as IFS, while `for` cuts by spaces, hence my comment.

Comment: `while` has no conception of `IFS`, but yes, `read` puts everything into variable if only one is provided. I don't remember in which case you need to specify `IFS=` to `read`. Maybe some ancient versions needed that…

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, the idea not to parse `ls` output is a good one, though the problem OP suffered is not due to parsing, so I thought it's important to give a solution to this immediate problem.

Answer (score 2):

`while` gets executed in a child shell, and it cannot modify parent's variables, in this case, `FOLDER`. You should try other ways. For example:

```
FOLDER=(`ls /tmp/backup`)
echo ${FOLDER[1]}
```

(will print the second file in there)

**NOTE**: Yes, I understand the problems of this solution, spaces, use of `ls`, etc. I just wanted to point out the problem with `while`. To complete the answer, yes, globbing should be used:

```
for dir in /tmp/backup/* ; do
    test -d "$dir" && do_stuff_with_dir("$dir")
done
```

And, by not dying of purism, the usual (at least in UNIXes) is *NOT* having spaces in filenames. It is bad for your health :)

Comment: FOLDER will not become an array after this assignment. And echo will be empty again. However the subshell thing is correct.

Comment: (I edited the post to make `FOLDER` an array; I had not yet seen @nshy's comment).

Comment: @chepner then issue with the spaces in filenames

Comment: Many files have spaces in their names. `ls` shoulld never be used in this manner. A glob should be used instead. Iterating over a glob using a `for` loop eliminates the need for a pipe and thus doesn't create a subshell.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, of course you're right... just jocking. I updated my response.

Answer (score 0):

As the others already mentioned one of the problems with the code above is modifying of a variable in a subshell. The other is using `+=` to populate the array. Unfortunately this just adds to zeroth element as a string, so that `FOLDERS[1]` stays undefined.

Comment: `array+=(element)` does not add to the zeroth element as a string - it appends a new element to the array.

Comment: It's bash! Keep you attention - I missed the parenthesis. @DennisWilliamson **Thank you**