# BASH - find regex in array, print found array items

Tags: arrays, regex, bash

I have tested the regex here:
http://regexr.com/3bchs

I cant get the array to only print the regex search terms.

```
files=(`ls $BACKUPDIR`)
daterange='(2015\-06\-)[0-9]+\s?'

for i in "${files[@]}"
do
        if [[ "$files[$i]" =~ $daterange ]];
         then
                 echo $i
         fi
done
```

Input: `2015-06-06 2015-06-13 2015-06-20 2015-06-27 2015-07-04 2015-07-11`

Output:

```
2015-06-06 
2015-06-13 
2015-06-20 
2015-06-27 
2015-07-04 
2015-07-11
```

Comment: You can try to execute your script with `bash -vx <script>` to see how the values are evaluated. This might shed some lights on what goes wrong.

Comment: You forgot the `{}` in `$files[$i]`. Try `${files[$i]}`

Comment: @anubhava I have added the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By running `bash -vx <script>` I found out that the files it was compering was wrong. I needed to change `$files[$i]` to `$i`.

`$files[$i]` = 2015-06-06[2015-06-06]

I have further improved my answer thanks to Etan Reisner comment. By not parsing output from `ls`.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11584156/3371795

```
#!/bin/bash

# Enable special handling to prevent expansion to a
# literal '/example/backups/*' when no matches are found. 
shopt -s nullglob

        # Variables
        YEAR=`date +%Y`
        MONTH=`date +%m`

        DIR=(/home/user/backups/backup.weekly/*)

        # REGEX - Get curent month
        DATE_RANGE='('$YEAR'\-'$MONTH'\-)[0-9]+\s?'


# Loop through dir
for i in "${DIR[@]}";
do
        # Compare dir name with date range
        if [[ "$i" =~ $DATE_RANGE ]];
        then
                # I have no idea what this is, works fine without it.
                [[ -d "$i" ]] 

                # Echo found dirs
                echo "$i"
        fi
done
```

Comment: You shouldn't be [parsing the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use a glob in that array instead (which may mean needing to strip paths in the loop probably but `basename` and [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) can do that for you).

Comment: I have updated my answer thanks @EtanReisner. Does anyone know what this is " [[ -d "$i" ]] ", I am unable to find anything on google.

Comment: `[[` is a bash-specific version of `[`/`test` with slightly different semantics. `-d` is "is a directory". Notice in the original it is `[[ -d "$folder" ]] && echo "$folder"` so that's "if $folder is a directory then echo $folder". On its own `[[ -d "$folder" ]]` just returns true or false and so in your code it does nothing.

Comment: Thanks bro, In my scenario I dont see the use for it here ?

Comment: Written as you have it it has, as I said, no purpose since it just returns true or false and doesn't affect or print anything. In the original with the `&&` it causes the `echo` to occur only when it returns true (i.e. the folder is a directory).