# How to store a directory's contents inside of an array

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to be able to store a directory's contents inside of an array. I know that you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A array

for i in Directory; do
     array[$i]=$i
done
```

to store directory contents in an associative array. But if there are subdirectories inside of a directory, I want to be able to store them and their contents inside of the same array. I also tried using:

```
declare -A arr1    

find Directory -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do
       arr1[$file]=$file
       echo "${arr1[$file]}"
    done
```

but this just runs into the problem where the array contents vanish once the while loop ends due to the subshell being discarded from the pipeline (not sure if I'm describing this correctly).

I even tried the following:

```
for i in $(find Directory/*); do
    arr2[$i]="$i"
    echo $i
done
```

but the output is a total disaster for files containing any spaces.

How can I store both a directory and all of its subdirectories (and their subdirectories if need be) inside of a single array?

Comment: You may consider exploring this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584029/how-can-i-store-a-list-of-directories-in-an-array

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays

Comment: What are you trying to archive? Why do you need to use an array?

Comment: @andlrc I'm writing a script that compares two directories and searches for duplicate files. The script stores the file names of the first directory in an array, and then searches through a 2nd directory to look for duplicates of the files. I thought the array would be a good way to store and compare the filenames, as well as the checksum of the files. I'm doing this as a way to help teach myself bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you know, you don't need associative arrays. A simpler way to add an element to a regular indexed array is:

```
array+=("$value")
```

Your `find|while` approach is on the right track. As you've surmised, you need to get rid of the pipeline. You can do that with process substitution:

```
while read -d $'\0' file; do
   arr1+=("$file")
done < <(find Directory -print0)
```

Another way to do this without `find` is with globbing. If you just want the files under `Directory` it's as simple as:

```
array=(Directory/*)
```

If you want to recurse through all of its subdirectories as well, you can enable `globstar` and use `**`:

```
shopt -s globstar
array=(Directory/**)
```

The globbing methods are really nice because they automatically handle file names with whitespace and other special characters.

Comment: I'm not sure OP is sure of what they want, I assume the answer could be: `my_arr=(Directory/*)`

Comment: The biggest downside to globstar and pathname expansion is that the expanded pathnames is stored in memory (all of them). And the execution is stalled until all pathnames are expanded. This might not be a problem considering OP want to store the result in an array. I have an open question asking OP why an array is needed at all.

Comment: @John Kugleman, thank you! Process substitution worked well for what I wanted. Although isn't the syntax supposed to be ``while read -d $'\0' file; do
   arr1+=("$file")
done < <(find Directory -print0)``